# php-amqplib Return Value from callback, to be accessbile in another page

Tags: php, amqp

I am creating a class `Result.php`. This class contains all processes to Send/Receive with php-amqplib , all is working fine. I can send and print result, in the function callback called by `basic_consume`. However, I want receive the process in another page `Main.php`.

The process works like this:

Result.php

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

...
...
class Result{
function Process(){
$conn = new AMQPStreamConnection.....

......


 $ch->basic_publish($msg,$exchange);
...
...
$ch->queue_bind($queue_name, '---xx--xx-');

..
..
$test_var_res="";
$callback=function($msg){
echo $msg; //this work good i can print the result
$test_var_res=$msg;
sleep(substr_count($msg->body, '.'));
$msg->delivery_info['channel']->basic_cancel($msg->delivery_info['consumer_tag']);
return $msg; 
}

 $ch->basic_qos(null, 1, null);
 $ch->basic_consume($queue_name, '', false, false, false, false, $callback);
//close conn and ch
...

return $callback ;
}
}
```

Main.php

```
require_once 'Result.php';
$test_AMQP=new Result();
echo $test_AMQP->Process();// no print nothing
```

> Error `Catchable fatal error</b>: Object of class PhpAmqpLib\Message\AMQPMessage could not be converted to string`

and if I try with `var_dump(get_object_vars($msg->body));` the result is null

I am sure that the key is the variable `$callback`, but not as I do that returns a value in the main.php page

Comment: Please read tutorial 6: http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-php.html